# Sphinx pocket android for Sinhala accent(English Language)

Tags: android, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I m trying to develop speech recognition application using Sphinx pocket android for Sinhala accent (English Language). But I don't know the procedure. Can someone help me?